# Facing a bottleneck of array

Tags: php, sql

I having below code which display correct result for me but unfortunately I cannot pass those result into my HTML page with certain return value.

This is my sql statement :

```
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM "._CONST_TBL_EVENT_COMMENT." WHERE event_id = $record";

if($rs = $db->Execute($stmt))
{
    while($rsa = $rs->FetchRow())
    {

        array_push($arrResult, array(
            "id" => $record,
            "name" => $alumni->getAlumniNameForEventComment($rsa['member_id']),
            "file_path" => $alumni->getAlumniImageForEventComment($rsa['member_id']),
            "content" => $rsa['text'],
            "date" => $rsa['modified_timestamp']
        ));
    }
}
```

This is the result I get :

```
Array ( [0] =>
        Array ( [id] => 1 [name] =>
             Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => alisdfsadf ) )
             [file_path] =>Array ( [0]=> Array ( [file_path] => hydrangeas_23197.jpg ) ) 
             [content] => test test test test 
             [date] => 2014-05-08 00:00:00 ) 
        [1] => 
        Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => 
             Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => billy ) ) 
             [file_path] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file_path] => ) )
             [content] => sdfasdfas test
             [date] => 2014-05-22 00:00:00 )
)
```

But I want my result show like this :

```
Array ( [0] => Array([id] => 1 [name] => alisdfsadf 
[file_path] => hydrangeas_23197.jpg 
[content] => test test test test 
[date] => 2014-05-08 00:00:00 )
```

How to I do this? I hope that someone can help me. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why do `getAlumniNameForEventComment` and `getAlumniImageForEventComment` return arrays instead of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions on the $alumni class appear to be returning arrays.
Based on the output that you've given, and trying to reverse engineer...

```
while($rsa = $rs->FetchRow())
{
    $allNamesArray = $alumni->getAlumniNameForEventComment($rsa['member_id']);
    $firstNameArray = $allNamesArray[0];
    $name = $firstNameArray['name'];

    // similar for file path.

    array_push($arrResult, array(
        "id" => $record,
        "name" => $name,
        "file_path" => $alumni->getAlumniImageForEventComment($rsa['member_id']),
        "content" => $rsa['text'],
        "date" => $rsa['modified_timestamp']
    ));
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `getAlumniXXXForEventComment` functions return arrays, you have to index them to get the strings you want.

```
if($rs = $db->Execute($stmt))
{
    while($rsa = $rs->FetchRow())
    {
        $nameArray = $alumni->getAlumniNameForEventComment($rsa['member_id']);
        $name = is_array($nameArray) ? $nameArray[0]['name'] : $nameArray;
        $fileArray = $alumni->getAlumniImageForEventComment($rsa['member_id']);
        $file = is_array($fileArray) ? $fileArray[0]['file_path'] : $fileArray;
        array_push($arrResult, array(
            "id" => $record,
            "name" => $name,
            "file_path" => $file,
            "content" => $rsa['text'],
            "date" => $rsa['modified_timestamp']
        ));
    }
```

Comment: i get offset error Warning: Illegal string offset 'file_path' in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.victorians93.com\sharelibrary\modules\event\Event.inc.php on line 77

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.victorians93.com\sharelibrary\modules\event\Event.inc.php on line 77

Warning: Illegal string offset 'file_path' in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.victorians93.com\sharelibrary\modules\event\Event.inc.php on line 77

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.victorians93.com\sharelibrary\modules\event\Event.inc.php on line 77

Comment: Does `getAlimniImageForEventComment` sometimes return a string, and other times returns an array? The example output you showed always has an array there.

Comment: I've added some type conditionals.